# Print out COUNT - SQL / PHP

Tags: php, sql, printing, count

I have this code:

```
$topics= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_topics WHERE forum_id=".$h['forum_id'].""); 
                print $topics; //This prints out 1, but should be 14?
```

As you can see, I select COUNT from my table. That table contains 14 rows. How can I print this out? As now, when I print out $topics, it just says **Resource Id #18.**

Comment: Did you read some tutorials/docs on using the mysql PHP functions?

Comment: Yes, I read about the COUNT(*) function, although it's done using a WHILE loop. I hope this can be avoided.

Comment: "The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(), and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the returned data." - mysql_query doc. You don't need a loop if you don't want a loop, but you need to use those functions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do:

```
$topics = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_topics WHERE forum_id=".$h['forum_id'].""); 
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($topics);
print $result['COUNT(*)'];
```

Comment: Then there is a problem with your query. Is there an entry in the table for `$h['forum_id']`'s value under the column `forum_id`?

Comment: Sorry! My bad. There was an error in my statement. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Then you need something like

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($topics))
{
   echo $row[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$topics= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as Count FROM forum_topics WHERE forum_id=".$h['forum_id']."");
```

`$topics` will not print `14`. The query returns `Resource ID` on `success` and `false` on `error`.

Source: [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

If you want to get the Count you can do,

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($topics) //You can use this since it's only one record
{
     echo $rows['Count'];
}
```

If you have to get multiple records you can use

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($topics))
{
     echo $rows['Count']."</br>";
}
```

Comment: For `SELECT` queries mysql_query returns a resource ID, or `false` on failure.

Comment: You are right `SELECT` returns resource ID, `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc` returns true.

Answer (score 0):

```
$topics= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM forum_topics WHERE forum_id=".$h['forum_id'].""); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($topics)){
    echo $row['count'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because $topics is a resource, not a result set. You need to get a result set(array) using mysql_fetch_assoc, mysql_fetch_array, or you can use mysql_fetch_row in this case.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php